# Is there a way to connect 2 headsets to 1 iPhone for conference calls?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, headphones, microphone

I am looking for a way to connect two headsets to the same iPhone that will work with popular software for audio calls, e.g. Zoom, Facetime, and Skype.

Basically, I am looking to put an audio splitter/mixer in front of the iPhone that would communicate with the output/input devices over Bluetooth, split/mix the signals, and communicate with the iPhone via Bluetooth or Lightning.

To achieve that kind of control I might have to use professional-grade recording equipment.

[image: Desired set up]

I found some products that do something similar, each of them lacks some essential capability:

- Diagram 1: [Product 1](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B0B28YW56G/) - no audio output, only for streaming
- Diagram 2: [Product 2](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08QMPBVK5/) - only audio output
- Diagram 3: [Product
  3](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08Q3YBR74/), [Product 4](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07WV9BRKW) - only one headset can have both audio and mic

[image: Available products]

The "headset" does not have to be a headset in a traditional sense, it could be separate mic, headphones, or even speakers.

I realize that the iPhone allows only one device with the handsfree BT profile to be attached at a time, so a direct connection is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find to this is the Poly Sync series. Two Sync 40 (and higher) devices can daisy chain and connect to an iPhone over BT.

The audio output and mic input will be mixed, the whole solution is very user friendly compared to alternatives I was considering initially in the question.

Have a look:

https://www.poly.com/de/de/products/phones/sync/sync-40